# Struct initializer with multiple steps that can fail

Tags: go

I have the following base code:

```
r1, err := OpenResource()
if err != nil { return err; }
defer r1.Close()

r2, err := OpenResource()
if err != nil { return err; }
defer r2.Close()

r3, err := OpenResource()
if err != nil { return err; }
defer r3.Close()

// Do something with r1, r2, r3
...
```

I want to wrap this into a struct, with a method `DoSomething`, which I would call as follows:

```
s, err := CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3()
if err != nil { return err }
defer s.Close()
s.DoSomethingWithR1R2R3()
```

My first approach of implementing this is:

```
func CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3() (*MyStruct, error) {
  s := MyStruct{}

  r1, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { return nil, err; }
  s.r1 = r1

  r2, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { r1.Close(); return nil, err; }
  s.r2 = r2

  r3, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { r1.Close(); r2.Close(); return nil, err; }
  s.r3 = r3

  return &s
}

func (s *MyStruct) Close() {
   s.r3.Close()
   s.r2.Close()
   s.r1.Close()
}

func (s *MyStruct) DoSomethingWithR1R2R3() { /* ... */ }
```

However, the `Close()` calls in the `Create()` function when an error occurs feel ugly and prone to errors.

An alternative approach that comes to mind is:

```
func CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3() (*MyStruct, error) {
  s := MyStruct{}
  success := false

  r1, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { return nil, err; }
  defer func() { if !success { r1.Close() } }()
  s.r1 = r1

  r2, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { return nil, err; }
  defer func() { if !success { r2.Close() } }()
  s.r2 = r2

  r3, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { return nil, err; }
  defer func() { if !success { r3.Close() } }()
  s.r3 = r3

  success = true
  return &s
}
```

This feels safer and cleaner, but the bool feels ugly, and when the Go formatter comes along, this makes the code quite a bit longer.

Is there a better common pattern of making sure all resources are closed with such a multi-stage initialization?

Answer (score 5):

You can perhaps push the `Close` calls to `*MyStruct`'s `Close`:

```
func (s *MyStruct) Close() {
    if s.r3 != nil {
        s.r3.Close()
    }
    if s.r2 != nil {
        s.r2.Close()
    }
    if s.r1 != nil {
        s.r1.Close()
    }
}
```

And update the first implementation of `CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3` as:

```
func CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3() (*MyStruct, error) {
  s := MyStruct{}

  r1, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { s.Close(); return nil, err; }
  s.r1 = r1

  r2, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { s.Close(); return nil, err; }
  s.r2 = r2

  r3, err := OpenResource()
  if err != nil { s.Close(); return nil, err; }
  s.r3 = r3

  return &s
}
```

Comment: Much better, that way you already have a `Close` function for the struct

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `err` as the return argument you don't need the extra `success` flag since `defer` will have access to the error value returned.

---

One way to reduce the repetition a little is to introduce a type that will manage a slice of `Closer`s. When calling close on this new type it would then loop over multiple `Closer`s, whether you have 3 or 300, and close them all. Say, something like this:

```
type Closer interface {
    Close()
}

type multiCloser struct {
    cc []Closer
}

func (mc *multiCloser) add(c Closer) {
    mc.cc = append(mc.cc, c)
}

func (mc *multiCloser) Close() {
    for _, c := range mc.cc {
        c.Close()
    }
}
```

With this the implementation of `CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3` would look like this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    // ...
    mc *multiCloser
}

func (ms *MyStruct) Close() {
    ms.mc.Close()
}

func CreateMyStructWithR1R2R3() (ms *MyStruct, err error) {
    ms = &MyStruct{mc: &multiCloser{}}
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            ms.Close()
        }
    }()

    if ms.r1, err = OpenResource(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ms.mc.add(ms.r1)

    if ms.r2, err = OpenResource(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ms.mc.add(ms.r2)

    if ms.r3, err = OpenResource(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ms.mc.add(ms.r3)

    return ms, nil
}
```